# no helpful error if command used in its own redefinition

Tags: errors, tex-core, error-writing

Why is it that tex does not (or cannot) produce an error when a command is used in a redefinition of itself? For example the plain file

```
\def\bf{\bf}

abc {\bf text}

\bye
```

just freezes, producing no error message. Similarly with LaTeX and `\renewcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\textbf}{\textbf}
\begin{document}
abc \textbf{text}
\end{document}
```

This came up for me recently because a large project stopped compiling due to a mistaken change in a package file that included a line like `\renewcommand\foo{ ... \foo ... }`. Because no error is produced, it took a long time to figure out what was wrong.

My guess is that scanning the argument of `\def\foo` or `\renewcommand\foo` in advance for the token `\foo` is possible, but not feasible in terms of efficiency. Is this correct, or is there another reason no error is produced?

Comment: it is not possible to catch that. Such definitions are not always faulty, recursive definitions can terminate as the state can change between the calls, see e.g. `\newcount\mycnt
\newcommand\foo{\ifnum \mycnt =0 \mycnt=1  foo \foo  \else blub\fi} 
\foo` (definitions for factorials e.g. do this).

Comment: That makes sense. But assuming I know I'm not reusing the command in its definition, would it be possible to define a `\newnorecursioncommand\foo` that did scan its argument for `\foo`? This could be a "deep" scan (also check the expansions of everything in the argument) or a "surface" scan (just check for the literal string `\foo`). I'm not sure what is possible

Comment: yes you can scan a definition body (etoolbox and xpatch e.g. do that for patching), but you wouldn't catch cases like \foo uses \bar and \bar uses \blub and \blub uses \foo.

Comment: it is complely normal to make definitions using undefined commands that are then defined before a command is used.

Comment: "Why is it that tex does not (or cannot) produce an error when a command is used in a redefinition of itself?" how would you program any sort of loop without doing that??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I understand the issue now. My main question at this point is whether there's a way to circumvent `\def\foo{\foo}` causing tex to freeze. As in, is there a way to *know* that `\foo` is not part of a recursive definition. If `\def\foo{\blub}` causes an error when `\foo` is expanded because `\blub` is not defined, why can't `\def\foo{\foo}` do the same (because `\foo` is not defined)? I'm surely missing something obvious

Comment: Some packages such as `xstring` and `fp` have macros that provide redefinitions, but not using the simple recursive method. For example, the result of a string manipulation can be put back into the same string. The result of a floating point calculation can be put back into the same number. If curious, have a look at their code.

Comment: tex has not frozen it  is looping this is famously impossible to detect in general "Turing Halting problem" add `\tracingall` to see it spinning, or use  `\def\bf{\bf.}` so it runs out of stack and stops

Comment: would you expect an error from equivalent versions such as `\loop\iftrue\repeat` ?

Comment: " (because \foo is not defined)?" ??? but `\foo` _is_ defined before it is used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So yes I was missing something obvious, of course it is defined, and this is the halting problem. I can delete the question or accept an answer referring to the comments

Comment: I'll write something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with `\def\bf{\bf}  \bf` tex is in a loop, such loops are impossible to detect in General ("Turing Halting problem") The good news is that it only gives a non terminating loop as it is a tail recursive macro that uses no stack. It is quite hard to write such a thing by accident. Similar "infinite" loops all give errors

`\def\bf{\bf.}\bf` gives `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].`

`\def\bf{.\bf}\bf` gives `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].`

`\def\bf{{\bf}}\bf` gives `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].`

So  automatically detecting cases that loop without error would be hard (even if it were not proved impossible:-)